# What is the meaning of the word 'Hayagarddabhi',used as a name of lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, name

Anusasana parva of Mahabharata contains the very famous Shiva Sahasranama Stotram discovered by sage Tandi.In 36th sloka I found a name "Hayagardabhi"[49 th name,I think] which literally means ' one whose vehicles are both horse and ass',but i think this is not the true sense and also irrelevant.If someone knows the actual meaning please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[this is what my search went for, it seems right interpretation](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kCSKV1etgkAC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=hayagardabbhi&source=bl&ots=RkfZgJXn48&sig=Uoc6Rgidv-eu_bTGPLSmODYtAjk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU8eGQhZbXAhWGqY8KHW4ZAcQQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) 
[image]

The meaning found in book name "The Thousands Names of Shiva" by Vijaya Kumar can be found on google books

Comment: You should add screen shot (or content) and mention name of book with name of translator (Author). Link alone answers are not allowed.

Comment: Yes i was about to edit but somehow its crashed